# I am looking for a tool, which can manage several Google + personal profiles (not pages!).

Tags: google

I need a tool, which can manage several google + personal profiles (not pages) on one dashboard! Has any of you created such a masterpiece and would like to sell it?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, asking for recommendations for tools is considered [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site since that often invites opinion-based answers and spam.

Comment: Hello dan.Thanks! How can I reask my question to recieve an answer?

Comment: Feel free to ask this in our chat room and maybe someone will have some ideas/experience with something helpful to you.